# Tridion New UI - Can we add a custom button anywhere like in classic UI

Tags: sdl-tridion, gui-extensions

In Classic UI, we have an ability to add custom buttons in the ribbonbar to perform certain actions. Likewise, Is there any possibility to customize the New UI? If yes, How it can be done?

The requirement is simply to have one custom button on the top as shown below and on click it should take us to some external page. We have achieved such functionalities in the classic UI with Anguilla framework but not sure how it can be done in New UI and also there is no supporting documentation we found for it.[image: Example screen with custom button]

It would be of great help if someone has any inputs on this and could guide us in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Experience Space (new UI) doesn't support UI extensions that Classic UI supports. That support will be added in Tridion Sites 10.